# How to remove used numbers from a list

Tags: excel, list

I must review a number of lists to check for used numbers. These lists contain values from 1 to 10000 but numbers were not issued in order. I have checked for duplicate numbers and they don't exist. As an example I've included the first 20 records of one list here with an explanation.

[image]

Working through this manually I would want to end up with:

```
2
3
4
14
20
```

As these numbers have not been used on the right hand list. Is there a way to achieve this in excel (or similar) as currently I'm stumped on how to check one list against another without having to set up a some form of dev environment to build an application to compare the lists?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to think in terms of "from ListA what is not in ListB" rather than "what is not in ListB that is in ListA". If your longer list is in ColumnA and the shorter in ColumnB then:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A1,B:B,0))
```

copied down to suit will return the values in A found in B, and where not found will return "#N/A" and, if placed in the correct row, the values missing from B will be those shown in the A column of the corresponding row.

For removal, filter columnB to select everything other than blanks and delete what then shows (will delete elements of ColumnA in the process, so maybe work on a copy).